# Downloaded WP but Nginx home page still showing

Tags: permissions, nginx

I am trying to install a second WP site on an Ubuntu 16 server running Nginx. I have successfully installed WordPress according to my server results, but I still only get the Nginx home page. I thought it might be the fact that the Group Owner was the User, so I changed group owner on web files to www-data:

```
microurb@vps148370:/var/www/dancortes.press/public_html$ ls -l
total 192
-rw-r--r--  1 microurb www-data     0 Oct  5 15:36 index.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data   418 Oct  8 17:07 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data 19935 Oct  8 17:07 license.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  7413 Oct  8 17:07 readme.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  5447 Oct  8 17:07 wp-activate.php
drwxrwxr-x  9 microurb www-data  4096 Oct  8 17:07 wp-admin
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data   364 Oct  8 17:07 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  1627 Oct  8 17:07 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  2599 Oct  8 17:17 wp-config.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  2853 Oct  8 17:07 wp-config-sample.php
drwxrwxr-x  5 microurb www-data  4096 Oct  8 17:19 wp-content
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  3286 Oct  8 17:07 wp-cron.php
drwxrwxr-x 18 microurb www-data 12288 Oct  8 17:07 wp-includes
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  2422 Oct  8 17:07 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  3301 Oct  8 17:07 wp-load.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data 34327 Oct  8 17:07 wp-login.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  8048 Oct  8 17:07 wp-mail.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data 16200 Oct  8 17:07 wp-settings.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data 29924 Oct  8 17:07 wp-signup.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  4513 Oct  8 17:07 wp-trackback.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  3065 Oct  8 17:07 xmlrpc.php
```

Still, I get only Nginx home page. I restarted Nginx a couple times.

I checked access and error logs and all I get is an error about code on the first site.

I checked the nginx access logs:

```
73.197.81.232 - - [08/Oct/2017:19:10:55 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
73.197.81.232 - - [08/Oct/2017:19:10:56 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

The error logs have an error regarding code on my first site:

```
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: success in /var/www/microurb.com/public_html/index.php on line 295" while reading upstream, client: 71.168.149.103, server: microurb.club, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "microurb.club"
2017/10/08 19:10:01 [alert] 22798#22798: *25 open socket #11 left in connection 3
2017/10/08 19:10:01 [alert] 22798#22798: aborting
2017/10/08 19:10:52 [alert] 23108#23108: *3 open socket #3 left in connection 3
2017/10/08 19:10:52 [alert] 23108#23108: aborting
```

I really do not know what to look for next. Why can I not see the WP site?

I decided to do an nginx -t and got this:

```
microurb@vps148370:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ nginx -t
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2017/10/08 19:41:25 [warn] 23341#23341: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2017/10/08 19:41:25 [emerg] 23341#23341: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I am not that much more enlightened now as to what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete file **index.html**. Once that is gone, index.php will work and WP will load.

Answer (score 0):

So after spending hours poring over the config files, I decided to try the one thing that someone suggested I not do, which is to change server_name from dancortes.press to www.dancortes.press. When I did that, the problem was solved. I can now view my the WordPress 4.8 core files I downloaded.

I learned that the reason I was instructed not to do so was because it was understood on the DNS side that this was a redirect, but it was not. This is a CNAME config on the DNS side of things.